# Unable to navigate to localhost (or 127.0.0.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, localhost, ports

This question should have been answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/727703/localhost8080-works-fine-but-localhost-doesnt), but I had to ask again because the resolution was inconclusive.

I am trying to configure my Tomcat's `server.xml` to work on TCP 8080 port. But it's always failing because the port 8080 is being used. I tried to run `netstat -ano` to find out what was using port 8080 and it seemed to be Firefox at that time (yes, it confuses me too). When I did this `http://localhost`, I got a 404 whereas doing `http://localhost:8080/` the address was working okay. The problem becomes apparent when I clik logout on my sample web application and it looks for `localhost/?logout` page. I can force the link to find `localhost:8080/?logout`, but this is a bodge, not a proper fix.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: `http://localhost` would send the browser to localhost port 80, not 8080. You say you get a 404 from that URL. So apparently _something_ is listening on port 80. Maybe some other web server is supposed to be acting as a frontend for tomcat here?

Comment: As for firefox, what makes you think it's listening on port 8080? Maybe you could edit your question to include whatever evidence you have for that?

Comment: @Kenster        It's a part of a commercial application and I cannot add any graphical evidence....... the problem is simply the address; `localhost` doesn't resolve to anything, but `localhost:8080`does.....and this is an SCM maintained app, so other developers have checked in the correct and working version of the app with the correct server.xml config.....my browser settings are identical to everyone else...

Comment: You previously said "when I do this `http://localhost`, I got a 404". That would mean some kind of HTTP server is listening on port 80 and responding to requests. Now you say "localhost doesn't resolve to anything". This seems to be contradictory. Are you expecting your application to work through the URL without a port number, or with the 8080 version of the URL?

Comment: @Kenster..... I tried `localhost` first....it gave me a 404. Then i tried with 8080 and it gave my the initial login page. Sorry for the contradictory statement.

Comment: Okay, so the app isn't working on port 80, and it does work on port 8080 aside from the logout page, and this is somehow firefox's fault? What do you think firefox is doing that's wrong?

Comment: @Kenster         I guess I found out the root cause..... Windows 8.1 System proc. is using port 80. And this is probably a bit more Windows 8.1 related problem....

Comment: Question makes no sense: if you are running your web server on port 8080, then you need to specify that in the url for firefox to know it should connect there instead of port 80.

Answer (score 2):

Run Resource monitor (if you are on windows. since you have not specified your os) by pressing the Windows key and then typing `resmon`.
Then in the `Network` tab you can see `Listening ports` and then check which program is using the port 80. Then take care of that.

If you are on linux, type this in command line:

```
sudo netstat -tapen | grep ":80 "
```

Comment: Annoyingly, it says `System NT & Kernel` as the process that is using port 80..... I am on Windows 8.1

Comment: @hagubear its IIS. try to disable it using the tuts given here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635851.aspx and tell me if that helped

Comment: @hagubear or this: https://learntech.imsu.ox.ac.uk/blog/?p=730

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I understood what was causing the issue.

When I started Tomcat, the service was trying to bind port 8080 to it's connectors (using `service.xml` file configs). But SQL server reporting services is the app that I wasn't familiar with. Apparently, MSSQLSERVER reporting services uses port 8080 by default and, if installed as a service already, will do so unless you disable it.

Once I disabled the service, my webapp worked perfectly. This is also a reason why binding it to 8055 was working temporarily (but it was not a logical solution anyway).

Thanks, to @TechLife for his answers :)